# jQuery CSS width attribute returning inconsistent on Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, markup

Below is a snippet of my jQuery where I am grabbing a dropdown and attempting to take the inline width style from it. My problem is that, on Safari I I am *not* getting a `newWidth` of 225.

targetSelect is `r_select` so I can't see why I Safari would return a different width than Firefox, for example.

```
// get the current select box
targetSelect = $(this);
newWidth = parseInt(targetSelect.css('width'));
```

My markup:

```
<select name="r_select" id="r_select" style="width: 225px; height: 50px; float: left;">
    <option>Mickelson</option>
    <option>Montgomerie</option>
    <option>Watson</option>
    <option>Casey</option>
</select>
```

I should add, that I am not having the same problem with this dropdown:

```
<select id="r_select_overlay" class="r_select_overlay_test no_style" name="r_select_overlay" style="width: 145px; height: 50px; float:left;">
        <option>Mickelson</option>
        <option>Montgomerie</option>
        <option>Watson</option>
        <option>Casey</option>
</select>
```

Comment: have you tried seeing what `newWidth = targetSelect.width();` gives?  I agree though it does seem odd.

Comment: Yes, that returns the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting outerWidth rather than simply width and see if that works.

http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Comment: Excellent, that fixed it! `newWidth = targetSelect.outerWidth();`

Comment: one more thing you could reset your css so that different browser default settings no longer interfeer